# Increment specific column value in a block dataset and loop several times

Tags: awk, sed, vi

I am trying to generate a huge dataset in the mentioned order.

```
4 0 1 642 643
4 642 643 1283 12
4 1283 1284 1924 1925
4 1924 1925 2565 2566
4 2565 2566 3206 3207
4 3206 3207 3847 3848
4 3847 3848 4488 4489
4 4488 4489 5129 5130

4 1 2 643 644
4 643 644 1284 1285
4 1284 1285 1925 1926
4 1925 1926 2566 2567
4 2566 2567 3207 3208
4 3207 3208 3848 3849
4 3848 3849 4489 4490
4 4489 4490 5130 5131

4 2 3 644 645
4 644 645 1285 1286
4 1285 1286 1926 1927
4 1926 1927 2567 2568
4 2567 2568 3208 3209
4 3208 3209 3849 3850
4 3849 3850 4490 4491
4 4490 4491 5131 5132
```

Description: There are 5 columns with the first column having a constant '4'. There are 8 rows in a block (data separated by a blank line).

Now, my idea is to copy the previous block (starting with lines 1-8) to the lines 10-17 and increment the number in columns 2-5 by one. This process (now lines 10-17 have to be copied in pasted in lines 19-27 and columns 2 -5 have to be incremented by 1) has to be iterated around 640 times to generate my required set.

Can anyone suggest me how to generate this type of dataset?

Comment: I see that I can use 'tail' to capture the last 8 lines in the file and then use 'awk' to do the incremental part but then I will have 640 files to append which is not an elegant way.  ex: $1 tail -8 MWE.txt > MWE1.txt  || $2 awk '{print $1, $2+1, $3+1, $4+1, $5+1}' MWE1.txt > op1

Comment: It's `vi`, not bash. `^[` is escape, `^M` is return.

Comment: @jhnc I tried the command in vi but it does not work. Does it work in visual mode or any specific conditions? And also is there a syntax error as the number of brackets don't match!!

Comment: I open a file in vi, pasted in the data you provided, then typed in the command I gave (the apparent linebreak after the doublequote is a space). Works on nvi and freebsd variants of vi. No idea if vim handles it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
cat <<\!>file
4 0 1 642 643
4 642 643 1283 12
4 1283 1284 1924 1925
4 1924 1925 2565 2566
4 2565 2566 3206 3207
4 3206 3207 3847 3848
4 3847 3848 4488 4489
4 4488 4489 5129 5130

!

for n in {0..640}; do sed 's/\S\+/$((&+'$n'))/2g;s/.\+/printf "%d %d %d %d %d" &/e' file;done
```

On retrospect this will work too:

```
for n in {0..640}; do sed 's/\S\+/$((&+'$n'))/2g;s/.\+/echo "&"/e' file;done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {
        flds[NR,fldNr] = $fldNr
    }
}
END {
    maxRecs = 3
    for (recNr=1; recNr<=maxRecs; recNr++) {
        for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=NR; lineNr++) {
            printf "%s", flds[lineNr,1]
            for (fldNr=2; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {
                printf " %s", flds[lineNr,fldNr]+(recNr-1)
            }
            print ""
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

.

```
$ cat file
4 0 1 642 643
4 642 643 1283 12
4 1283 1284 1924 1925
4 1924 1925 2565 2566
4 2565 2566 3206 3207
4 3206 3207 3847 3848
4 3847 3848 4488 4489
4 4488 4489 5129 5130
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
4 0 1 642 643
4 642 643 1283 12
4 1283 1284 1924 1925
4 1924 1925 2565 2566
4 2565 2566 3206 3207
4 3206 3207 3847 3848
4 3847 3848 4488 4489
4 4488 4489 5129 5130

4 1 2 643 644
4 643 644 1284 13
4 1284 1285 1925 1926
4 1925 1926 2566 2567
4 2566 2567 3207 3208
4 3207 3208 3848 3849
4 3848 3849 4489 4490
4 4489 4490 5130 5131

4 2 3 644 645
4 644 645 1285 14
4 1285 1286 1926 1927
4 1926 1927 2567 2568
4 2567 2568 3208 3209
4 3208 3209 3849 3850
4 3849 3850 4490 4491
4 4490 4491 5131 5132
```

Just change `maxRecs=3` to `maxRecs=640` or whatever value you like.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl one-liner

```
 perl -0777 -ne ' while( $i++<3) { s/(?!^)(\d+)/$1+1/gme; print "$_\n" } '
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat saideep.txt
4 0 1 642 643
4 642 643 1283 12
4 1283 1284 1924 1925
4 1924 1925 2565 2566
4 2565 2566 3206 3207
4 3206 3207 3847 3848
4 3847 3848 4488 4489
4 4488 4489 5129 5130

$ perl -0777 -ne ' while( $i++<3) { s/(?!^)(\d+)/$1+1/gme; print "$_\n" } ' saideep.txt
4 1 2 643 644
4 643 644 1284 13
4 1284 1285 1925 1926
4 1925 1926 2566 2567
4 2566 2567 3207 3208
4 3207 3208 3848 3849
4 3848 3849 4489 4490
4 4489 4490 5130 5131

4 2 3 644 645
4 644 645 1285 14
4 1285 1286 1926 1927
4 1926 1927 2567 2568
4 2567 2568 3208 3209
4 3208 3209 3849 3850
4 3849 3850 4490 4491
4 4490 4491 5131 5132

4 3 4 645 646
4 645 646 1286 15
4 1286 1287 1927 1928
4 1927 1928 2568 2569
4 2568 2569 3209 3210
4 3209 3210 3850 3851
4 3850 3851 4491 4492
4 4491 4492 5132 5133


$
```

Comment: One way to get a desired number of iterations: `for my $i (1..N)`

Comment: @zdim.. yes thank you!.. btw, I think I have improved on formatting now :-)

Answer (score 0):

These `vi` commands call awk to perform the task:

---

`:map z G{yGPG{!}awk '{for(i=NF;i>1;--i)++$i;print}'`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>CR</kbd>`1GO`<kbd>ESC</kbd>`640iz`<kbd>ESC</kbd>`"add@a`

---

- `:map z` **(…)** <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>CR</kbd> defines a macro z
- `G{yGP` duplicates the final paragraph of the file
- `G{!}` executes awk on the final paragraph

  - `for(i=NF;i>1;--i)++$i;` increments all fields except first
  - `print` the modified line
- `1GO`<kbd>ESC</kbd>`640iz`<kbd>ESC</kbd> prepares 640 invocations of z
- `"add@a` runs the prepared commands

Comment: I don't understand when shall Ctrl+V (Visual mode), CR CR be executed. From my knowledge, a macro is defined in visual mode. If I follow the order you mentioned I get 640 prints of z in insert mode (due to 640iz).

Comment: Ctrl-V is not visual mode while you are defining a macro with `:map`. It means "quote next character" in this context. You can test if the macro was defined correctly by typing `:map`<kbd>CR</kbd> and checking that there is a definition for z. It looks like vim doesn't do the right thing if you try to paste the command sequence, so type it in manually.

Comment: I tried mapping. But it is not doing the required. Instead of 640 iterations, I tried only doing 2 and it resulted in repeated results (whereas the solution shall be as posted in the question).

Comment: What do you mean by "repeated results"?

Comment: After running 2 iterations, I have output as                                                                     4 2 3 644 645 ||
4 644 645 1285 1286 ||
4 1285 1286 1926 1927 ||
4 1926 1927 2567 2568 ||
4 2567 2568 3208 3209 ||
4 3208 3209 3849 3850 ||
4 3849 3850 4490 4491 ||
4 4490 4491 5131 5132 || and this data repeats 4 times erasing the previous data.

Comment: I am starting from the datafile you provided that contains three blocks. At a minimum,  the file must contain 9 lines (8 data + 1 blank). Otherwise "paragraph" will mean "entire file" and awk will be passed the entire contents of the file on each iteration and not just a single block.

Answer (score 0):

The following bash script does the required as mentioned in the question.

```
#!/bin/bash
for k in {1..639}
do
 echo "$k th iteration"
 tail -8 MWE.txt > i
 awk '{print $1, $2+1, $3+1, $4+1, $5+1}' i > j
 cat j >> MWE.txt
done
```

Note here I increment the loop counter variable 'k' until 639 as I provide the first set of data (initial 8 rows of data).